# contentflow autostart does not work in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, carousel

I have created a test carousel with contentflow

http://www.invest-champagne-ardenne.fr/test-carousel

Everything is fine except that the autostart does not work in firefox.

I have looked a solution for hours but i can't find the reason why it does not work.

Do you have any idea ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Console shows the following error:

> `this.AddOns[B] is undefined @ http://www.invest-champagne-ardenne.fr/design/cadevinstitutionnel/javascript/contentflow.js:37`

This is coming from method `setAddOnConf` which is apparently being called before the add-ons loaded. If you look at how the add-ons are being loaded:

```
addScript : function(B) {
  if (this.Browser.IE || this.Browser.WebKit || this.Browser.Konqueror) {
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + B
                     + '"><\/script>')
  } else {
    var A = document.createElement("script");
    A.src = B;
    A.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(A)
  }
},
```

And here we have a bug in `contentflow.js` - this assumes that dynamically added scripts will load synchronously in all browsers but Internet Explorer and WebKit-based browsers. That's something that Firefox is no longer doing starting with Firefox 4 (see [bug 591981](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=591981) for more details). Simplest fix: remove the `if` statement and do `document.write()` for all browsers. The other option would be adding `async="false"` attribute to the dynamically inserted script, I'm not sure however what the browser support matrix looks like here.